# How to copy Python/Anaconda virtual environment from one computer to another?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have two environments on one machine : "base" and "image_analytics".
I have another computer which has only base environment. I want to copy/clone "image_analytics" environment to my second machine as it is. What are the steps to follow? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you only need to duplicate the libraries installed?

Comment: I want to duplicate everything in that enviornment and make same env in new machine

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in Anaconda docs:

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments

Comment: For a variety of reasons, [link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627). Please edit your answer and include the main points directly in your question. See [answer].